# Android empty edittext and button

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem about button clicking. I have 7 edittext covered with double value. When I dont enter at least one edittext and after click button app crashes. Also when enter all values app runs well.

Whats the problem ı dont know and ı am really beginner at programing. Thanks for help from now

I tried toast message set eror message if else statements but nothing works.

**This Is My Main Activity Code**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void baslat (View view) {
    TableLayout resultLayout = findViewById(R.id.resultLayout);
    resultLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Keyboard hide kısmı //
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(resultLayout.getWindowToken(), 0);

        //Virgülden sonraki basamak sayısını ayarlayan kısım //
    NumberFormat sonUmut = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    sonUmut.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);




            // T1 Hedef Hesaplama Kısmı //

    EditText t1 = findViewById(R.id.t1);
    EditText yapilan = findViewById(R.id.yapilan);
    EditText ayGun = findViewById(R.id.ayGun);
    EditText bugun = findViewById(R.id.bugun);
    TextView t1Sonuc = findViewById(R.id.t1Sonuc);

    double t1Veri = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText().toString());

    double yapilanVeri = Double.parseDouble(yapilan.getText().toString()); //MULTI USE
    double ayGunVeri = Double.parseDouble(ayGun.getText().toString()); //MULTI USE
    double bugunVeri = Double.parseDouble(bugun.getText().toString()); //MULTI USE



    double t1Formul = (t1Veri - yapilanVeri) / (ayGunVeri - bugunVeri);
    String t1Formula = sonUmut.format(t1Formul);
    t1Sonuc.setText(""+t1Formula+"");



            // T1 Hedef Hesaplama Kısmı //

                      // // // //

            // T2 Hedef Hesaplama Kısmı //

    EditText t2 = findViewById(R.id.t2);
    TextView t2Sonuc = findViewById(R.id.t2Sonuc);

    double t2Veri = Double.parseDouble(t2.getText().toString());

    double t2Formul = (t2Veri - yapilanVeri) / (ayGunVeri - bugunVeri);
    String t2Formula = sonUmut.format(t2Formul);
    t2Sonuc.setText(""+t2Formula+"");

            // T2 Hedef Hesaplama Kısmı //

                    // // // //

            // Adet Hedef Hesaplama Kısmı //

    EditText adet = findViewById(R.id.adet);
    TextView adetSonuc = findViewById(R.id.adetSonuc);

    double adetVeri = Double.parseDouble(adet.getText().toString());

    double adetFormul = t2Formul / (yapilanVeri / adetVeri);
    String adetFormula = sonUmut.format(adetFormul);
    adetSonuc.setText(""+adetFormula+"");

            // Adet Hedef Hesaplama Kısmı //

                    // // // //

            // TL Verim Hesaplama Kısmı //

    EditText saat = findViewById(R.id.saat);
    TextView tlVerimSonuc = findViewById(R.id.tlVerimSonuc);

    double saatVeri = Double.parseDouble(saat.getText().toString());

    double tlVerimFormul = (t2Formul / saatVeri);
    String tlVerimFormula = sonUmut.format(tlVerimFormul);
    tlVerimSonuc.setText(""+tlVerimFormula+"");

            // TL Verim Hesaplama Kısmı //

                    // // // //

        // Adet Verim Hesaplama Kısmı //

    TextView adetVerimSonuc = findViewById(R.id.adetVerimSonuc);

    double adetVerimFormul = (adetFormul / saatVeri);
    String adetVerimFormula = sonUmut.format(adetVerimFormul);
    adetVerimSonuc.setText(""+adetVerimFormula+"");

        // Adet Verim Hesaplama Kısmı //

                // // // //

        //  T1 Tamamlanan Kısmı //

        TextView t1TamamlananSonuc = findViewById(R.id.t1Tam);

        double t1TamFormul = (yapilanVeri / t1Veri) * 100;

        String t1TamFormula = sonUmut.format(t1TamFormul);
        t1TamamlananSonuc.setText("% " + ""+t1TamFormula+"");

        //  T1 Tamamlanan Kısmı //

                // // // //

        //  T2 Tamamlanan Kısmı //

        TextView t2TamamlananSonuc = findViewById(R.id.t2Tam);

        double t2TamFormul = (yapilanVeri / t2Veri) * 100;

        String t2TamFormula = sonUmut.format(t2TamFormul);
        t2TamamlananSonuc.setText("% " + ""+t2TamFormula+"");

        //  T2 Tamamlanan Kısmı //

                // // // //

        // Ay Tamamlanan Kısmı //


        TextView ayTamamlananSonuc = findViewById(R.id.ayTam);

        double ayTamFormul = ((bugunVeri - 1) / ayGunVeri) * 100;

        String ayTamFormula = sonUmut.format(ayTamFormul);
        ayTamamlananSonuc.setText("% " + ""+ayTamFormula+"");



    }

}
```

Comment: Kindly add your code in question as without that , no one can figure out what is wrong there ?

Comment: All right ı will thank you

Comment: Show us the error after crashing, u can find it on logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when trying to convert your String to Double, it will crash because your text is Empty, and you can't convert Empty text to Double.

Try below code for every editText:-

```
//init EditText
 EditText editText1=findViewById(R.id.t1);
 EditText editText2=findViewById(R.id.t2);
 EditText editText3=findViewById(R.id.t3);
 ...
 
 //set value
 double value1 = Double.parseDouble(!String.valueOf(editText1.getText()).isEmpty() ? String.valueOf(editText1.getText()) : "0");
 double value2 = Double.parseDouble(!String.valueOf(editText2.getText()).isEmpty() ? String.valueOf(editText2.getText()) : "0");
 double value3 = Double.parseDouble(!String.valueOf(editText3.getText()).isEmpty() ? String.valueOf(editText3.getText()) : "0");
 ...
```

In the above code. when editText is Empty that time it will assign a Zero( 0 ) otherwise is set a editText Value

Answer (score 0):

I try to guess, in some place of your code you are calling some convert method like `Double.parseDouble`, and you pass as argument your `editText.getText()`.

So when trying to convert your `String` to `Double`, it will crash because your text is **Empty**, and you can't convert **Empty** text to **Double**.

> **Solution 1** : Try to surround your Convert Method with `try/catch`.
>
> **Solution 2** : Try to use ***Input Control***, for example: Check if all your fields are not **Empty**, after that you do your stuff